# Typescript how to pass T[keyof T] to list of objects with working types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I've got DataGrid component in my React project. I want it to be type safe, so I made generic type T for data and K as keyof T for column, but when I want to create columns Typescript doesn't know the type of property instead it gives type as union.
Sample interfaces:

```
interface DataGridProps<T extends object> {
    data: T[];
    columns: Array<ColumnProps<T, keyof T & string>>;
    idField: keyof T & string;
}
```

```
interface ColumnProps<T, K extends keyof T> {
    field: K,
    sorter?: (a: T[K], b: T[K]) => number;
    formatter?: (value: T[K]) => string;
}
```

Here is playground with problem:
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA4lYATABSgHsAHAZwB4AVZCAD0hD3OWICMArCBMAPmQBvALAAoZBOR4McAFzJqAbQC6AbjGTkCYgBsArgFsQ5eQEEoUOAE9KAYV2GQRMlWoAaZAGsIV4jAXIAGTI5GC4IADmfHzq4pL4AGLAEDp48t6+-rTBoeERsQC+YmKgkLCIKPb6Rs4UNB4A0nSMEMysGX4KAiJxEjDJqfINbhqS5MRQZQD88gAUcgqKDcoe7PJKywCUyAC8AiCG7NCxmjATBhjTcwBucPoQ60vK23shYaD5YkWiJeDQ8EhkARoOMQD0JPh5AcDEcoCM4iA4AYHm88vCJIgwMBrij2MRdBA4CB4d8xNpjGBkBFcIQSBR5OhMDh8LUqMCoKCBDshKNpJh5IpBJDkABGDyI5HyABE1AgoSlHkx2JRYT0EAKK1G2mqxgF4Mk-RSaWQUvwCtGEnGk2gcwW0Nhqyhh2gLwEYtGGvRyESA2NprwUq+xVE5NCWgcRhMyCqjlZlHZoI8HX8CeIID4Kl2o0FhsGJrNHitZVtTph0EdyHtLt2bo1wdDlO1jhFyHkMZqdLZILTHn9Uq5PLiub9BdGRZtyHmpYdyDWledUFdopJQA)

I tried:

Pass columns as list inline (not working)

```
const gridProps: DataGridProps<Person> = {
  data: [{id: 1, name: "Test", active: true}],
  columns: [{
    field: "id",
    sorter: (a: number, b: number) => 1,
  }],
  idField: "id"
}
```

Create list of columns (not working)

```
const columns: ColumnProps<Person, keyof Person>[] =
  [{field: "id", sorter: (a: number, b: number) => 1}]
```

Creating individual column with generic works, but is there any other solution that not require that much code?

```
const column1 : ColumnProps<Person, "id"> = {
  field: "id",
  sorter: (a: number, b: number) => 1,
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAxoBN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame While your code may eliminate the type errors, it introduces `never`, which again means more checks in other code areas. The problem is with the sorter's signature during the assignment. Please see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76489234/11104618

Comment: @rishichawda what's the problem with never? It won't be reached  anyway, since condition `K extends K` is always true

Comment: @wonderflame your approach seems to work. When field is set to "id" sorter takes number, when "name" sorter takes string etc, but I wonder why adding K extends K works?

Comment: @Rolczak if that works for you I can write an answer explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually really close to the desired solution. The problem is in `ColumnProps` with the `K` parameter. When you use `ColumnProps` in `DataGridProps` you pass `K` as `keyof T & string` which is resulted in a union, thus in the `sorter` `T[K]` is resolved to all possible values.

Example:

```
type Obj = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
};

type Func<Obj, K extends keyof Obj> = (value: Obj[K]) => null;

// (value: string | number | boolean) => null
type Result = Func<Obj, keyof Obj>;
```

Since, we would expect to get:

```
type Result = ((value: string) => null) | ((value: number) => null) | ((value: boolean) => null)
```

this method doesn't work and the solution is [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Basically, we need to check if `K` extends something to distribute it, but we must be sure that this condition will be always true. Possible ones are `K extends K` or `K extend any`, .etc.

Testing:

```
type Func<Obj, K extends keyof Obj> = K extends K
  ? (value: Obj[K]) => null
  : never;

// ((value: string) => null) | ((value: number) => null) | ((value: boolean) => null)
type Result = Func<Obj, keyof Obj>;
```

Looks great! Now, let's apply the same logic to `ColumnProps`:

```
type ColumnProps<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends K
  ? {
      field: K;
      sorter?: (a: T[K], b: T[K]) => number;
      formatter?: (value: T[K]) => string;
    }
  : never;
```

Usage:

```
const columns: ColumnProps<Person, keyof Person>[] = [
  { field: 'id', sorter: (a, b) => a + b}, // a and b are inferred as numbers
];
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHA4lYATABSgHsAHAZwB4AVZCAD0hD3OWICMArCBMAPmQBvALAAoZMjwY4ALmTUA2gF0A3GIkJiAGwCuAWxDk5AQShQ4AT0oBhbfpBEyVagBpkAawgXiMecgBkyORguCAA5nx8auLI+ABiwBBaeHKe3r60gcGhYdEAvmJiYBakKLa6Bo4UNG4A0nSMEMysaT7yAgC8yPUMTCzd6sgA-EKDEhIwiclytdHj4+TEUJBQQ3IAFLLyCrVKbuxyirsAlMgdAiD67NBz88gwS3oYK2vI6wBucLoQhztKp+cgiFQLkxsgCjE5CAIO8boVRKAVvAkMgCNBFiBRjF8FCrnCYiA4HofkCcrdEGBgLC5OxiNoIHAQPl4ZpDGBkGFcIQSBQ5OhMDh8FUqGioBjOliJFJMHIFIJYilkABGNyE4lyADk1AgwQ1bgpVJJIR0KDye0GmgqhllYJEMXmkySio1+D1YIki2W0A2W0uemuUH2uP90ABAhVYLyLkG5uxeASTs1rujojy0TErOCyEt9iMyHK9mFlFFGLcrV8JeIID4yjOyAUg3ljumyBdeD1QSWKx9+zDyDgyAA1Mh2FHkAB6cf9-vMEf9qAoUAwaALvD91h+gPkMSqFlVrM5gxKuQFyo8kXoqtuNsaiV2iZTZ3Jwae7tvX14wMj4MBvsR1PREAA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the signature of the `ColumnProps.sorter` method's signature during the assignment.

**Fix:**

```
const gridProps: DataGridProps<Person> = {
  data: [{id: 1, name: "Test", active: true}],
  columns: [{
    field: "id",
    // Use Person[keyof Person] because that is the correct signature.
    sorter: (a: Person[keyof Person], b: Person[keyof Person]) => 1,
  }],
  idField: "id"
}

const columns: ColumnProps<Person, keyof Person>[] =
  [{field: "id", sorter: (a: Person[keyof Person], b: Person[keyof Person]) => 1}]

const column1 : ColumnProps<Person, "id"> = {
  field: "id",
  // This doesn't need Person[keyof Person] because typescript
  // knows we are targeting "id" property of Person which stores a number.
  sorter: (a: number, b: number) => 1,
}
```

**Explanation:**
The reason why your code doesn't work is when you say `keyof Person`, what you're really telling Typescript is that it can be any of the types defined in the person interface. In addition to that, when defining `ColumnProps`, you said that sorter takes arguments that are of type `T[K]`, which is `string | number | boolean`.

So in your case, it can be a `number`, `string` or `boolean` since you define your Person interface as

```js
interface Person{
  id: number,
  name: string,
  active: boolean,
}
```

But when you defined one instance, you said I will target the `id` key. So, Typescript can now look at the Person interface and understand - alright, since `id` is of number type, I'll let you assign a number.

So, if you wanted to handle only number types to be sorted, then this would be the way to go:

```js
interface ColumnProps<T, K extends keyof T> {
    field: K,
    sorter?: (a: number, b: number) => number;
    formatter?: (value: T[K]) => string;
}
```

But since you want a generic `sorter` method, you would have to be consistent with the signature when using the type for which you defined the generic. Hence the fix I wrote at the start of the answer.

Comment: This solution is not giving me what I want because sorter is still union type, so I cannot make this sorter without type checking or assertions. Field is K type so T[K] should poinitng to correct field type not union